# Edit pycharm interpreter via command line

Tags: unix, pycharm, interpreter

Is there a way to update/edit pycharm interpreters without the gui? IE editing some configuration file or something?

I am running pycharm community version 2018.2 in unix environment

Comment: Sadly, AFAIK, there's no way to change the pycharm helpers that power your interpreter. You can try editing the files that pycharm uploads to the remote location. `.pycharmhelpers`

Answer (score 1):

The pycharm interpreter uses a defined python installation on the machine, either python or anaconda or something. I believe you can update the python via running it from it's installation location and piping or whatever you need from there.